# Android layout 960x540 which quilifer

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to write down a layout for device with screen resolution 960x540, I tried to create  this folder

```
layout-port-960x540
layout-land-960x540
```

but same does not have any effects, what should i ckeck to be sure that those xml files will be loaded?
Thanks

Comment: Resolution-specific qualifiers (e.g., `-960x540`) have been deprecated for some time and are no longer even documented.

Comment: Create a UI design that can fluidly handle a wider range of resolutions, so 960x540 is no longer special.